# Laravel Eloquent filter product's attributes

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am making a filter function for products. I have 2 models: `Product` and `Attribute` (BelongsToMany relationship)

Attributes table:

```
id      name
-------------
1       RAM
2       HDD
```

Products table:

```
id      name
-----------------
1       Product 1
2       Product 2
3       Product 3
4       Product 4
```

And the pivot table look like:

```
id      attribute_id            product_id     value
----------------------------------------------------
1       1 (RAM)                 1              8GB
2       2 (HDD)                 1              256GB
3       1 (RAM)                 2              8GB
4       2 (HDD)                 2              256GB
5       1 (RAM)                 3              4GB
6       2 (HDD)                 4              512GB
```

When filter products, user select `RAM => [4GB, 8GB]` and `HDD => 256GB`.

I want to get products that have `RAM - 4GB` **OR** `RAM - 8GB` **AND** `HDD - 256GB`. It means product has attributes `RAM - 4GB, HDD - 256GB` **AND** `RAM - 8GB, HDD - 256GB` will be satisfied the filters. Compared to my above database, I will get products with ID 1 and 2 (Product 3 have `RAM 4GB` but doesn't have `HDD 256`, so doesn't count).

Here are my code, but it doesn't work as I expected.

```
$products = Product::whereHas('attributes', function ($query) {
            $query->whereIn('attribute_id', [1, 2]);
            $query->whereIn('value', ['4GB', '8GB', '256GB']);
        })->get();
```

or

```
$products = Product::whereHas('attributes', function ($query) {
            $query->where(function ($query) {
                $query->where('attribute_id', 1)
                    ->whereIn('value', ['4GB', '8GB']);
            })->orWhere(function ($query) {
                $query->where('attribute_id', 2)
                    ->whereIn('value', ['256GB']);
            });
        })->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```php
$products = Product::whereHas('attributes', function ($query) {
    $query
        ->whereIn('attribute_id', [1, 2])
        ->whereIn('value', ['4GB', '8GB', '256GB']);
})->get();
```

You have to chain those `whereIn()`.

In the [method signature](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_whereIn) you can note the third optional `$boolean` parameter:

```php
whereIn(string $column, mixed $values, string $boolean = 'and', bool $not = false)
```

Update: [raw SQL](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/71mXdjQuWi5Egk26A4m841/6). I'd rather go with raw Eloquent query in your case.

Comment: "*You have to chain those `whereIn()`.*", I am not sure that's why he is not getting the right result set.

Comment: Nobody knows, we don't have plain SQL from `->toSql()` or so to debug more precisely)

Comment: @Tarasovych it doesn't work as I expected. The result includes product #3 that has RAM 4GB. My expectation is only 2 products (#1 and #2) because product #3 doesn't have attribute HDD 256GB.

Comment: Please, take a look on raw SQL and tell if that is what you want

Comment: @Tarasovych I got an empty array.


$results = \DB::select(\DB::raw("select products.id, products.name from products
inner join attribute_product on products.id = product_id
where
    (
      (attribute_product.value = '256gb') and (attribute_product.attribute_id = 2)
    )
    and
    (
      ((attribute_product.value in ('4gb', '8gb')) and (attribute_product.attribute_id = 1))
    )"));

Comment: Because there are no matches, you can try query by link I provided. The query is exactly what you've described in your question

Comment: @Tarasovych yes, I did try your query in the link and it returned an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

i think Values should also be different model so the database schema is

### id      attribute_id            product_id     value_id

1          10                       3           10

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Use the method ->when() to make your query more dynamic:

```
/*
sample $request->attributes
[2 => ['4GB', '8GB'], 5 => ['256GB']];
*/
$attributes = $request->attributes;
    
$products = Product::when(count($request->attributes), function($query) use ($request){
        $query->whereHas('attributes', function ($query) use ($request) {
            $firstCondition = 0;
            foreach($request->attributes as $attrID => $value){
                if($firstCondition < 1){
                    $query->where(function ($query) use ($attrID, $value) {
                        $query->where('attribute_id', $attrID)
                            ->whereIn('value', $value);
                    });
                } else {
                    // remove orWhere from here so both attributes must be TRUE 
                    // The way that is now (first condition) OR (second condition) will return all the TRUE conditions
                    $query->where(function ($query) use ($attrID, $value) {
                        $query->where('attribute_id', $attrID)
                            ->whereIn('value', $value);
                    });
                }
                $firstCondition++;
            }
        });
    })->get();
```